# Windows batch: Command not recognized

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

If I ran below batch file then it's working and `7z` and `timeout` is recognized

```
FOR %%A IN (% C:\dfsdf_asdffd\dd_etgvssd%\*.axml) DO (
setlocal
 set filename=%%A
 call :tests
)
exit /b

:tests
set newname=%filename:~14%
set transname=%filename:~25%
timeout 5
7z e %newname%
move *.xml Agile_Original.xml
exit /b
```

But If I ran below batch file then `cmd` is saying that `7z`, `timeout` is not recognized.

```
For /F "tokens=1* delims==" %%A IN (Input_values.properties) DO (
    IF "%%A"=="path" set path=%%B
    IF "%%A"=="url" set url=%%B
    IF "%%A"=="username" set username=%%B
    IF "%%A"=="password" set password=%%B
    IF "%%A"=="location" set location=%%B
)
FOR %%A IN (% C:\dfsdf_asdffd\dd_etgvssd%\*.axml) DO (
    setlocal
     set filename=%%A
     call :tests
    )
    exit /b

    :tests
    set newname=%filename:~14%
    set transname=%filename:~25%
    timeout 5
    7z e %newname%
    move *.xml Agile_Original.xml
    exit /b
```

As you can see I just added one loop to read contents from `properties` file

Comment: Is 7z in your PATH environment variable? I can't find "timeout" in your example

Comment: @FlorianStraub added `timeout` and yes I 7z is in my path variable. when I run without `properties` file extraction then it's executing.

Comment: don't use `%path%` as a user variable. It's a system variable that tells windows where to find it's executables. Change it to another name.

Comment: (same applies to `%username%`, although it's not _that_ critcal))

Comment: @Stephan yes I agree with you. I used not use `%path%` as a variable. Thanks. Please post it as answer, I will accept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

don't use `%path%` as a user variable. It's a system variable that tells windows where to find it's executables. Change it to another name.

(same applies to `%username%`, although it's not *that* critcal))